# tomcat:8 docker with python 3.6

Tags: python, docker, tomcat

So I have a web application that runs on tomcat 8.5. I am moving the application over to docker, and have created a tomcat:8 container that runs the program. However, the application is using some python scrips, and I am having trouble with installing anything later that python 3.4 in the container, as the tomcat image comes with Debian 8. I have tried to use tomcat:10.0 instead, witch comes with Debian 10, but this will not start my application.

Is it possible t start a tomcat 8 container with Debian 10, or is it possible to get python 3.6 in the tomcat:8 container without building it up from scratch?

Comment: Do you need python3.6 precisely would 3.7.3(latest stable) do the job for you?

Comment: Can you be more precise in regard of the troubles you are facing when trying to install `python3` on top of the `tomcat:8` image? I just installed it without problems. I can share a minimal `Dockerfile` if this is what you are looking for

Comment: @NeoAnderson I beleive anything abouve 3.6 should work, but I don't seem to be able to install anything above 3.4

Comment: @NeoAnderson When I do apt install python3.6 (or 3.7), it starts the process, but I get the error messages E: Unable to locate package python3.7 and  E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.7'. I would love it if you had a minimal Dockerfile (sorry for two comments, I didn't see right away that it was you in both comments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Dockerfile for creating an image with Tomcat 8.5.57 and Python 3.7.3 (as of the time of this post):

```
FROM tomcat:8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install python3 && apt-get -y clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

As far as I can tell Debian has only package `python3` rather than separate packages for different Python versions, which is why you couldn't find package `python3.6` or `python3.7`.

Also package lists take a lot of space and get out of date quickly, so they are never included in the images. That's why you must always fetch them before installing new packages and remove them immediately after.

Comment: If I need to install requirements too, is it as straightforward as with [the official guide](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/python#create-a-dockerfile-in-your-python-app-project): `RUN pip install ...`?

Comment: You need to install pip using apt first (I think the package is called `python3-pip`), but other than that yes.